# What is this wacky definition of \@makefnmark trying to accomplish?

Tags: footnotes, package-writing, debugging

A journal style file that shall remain nameless contains this code:

```
\def\thestandardf@@tnote{\@arabic\c@footnote}
\def\@makefnmark{%
  \hbox{%
    \ifx\thefootnote\thestandardf@@tnote
    \@textsuperscript{\fontencoding{U}\selectfont\@thefnmark}%
    \else
      \@textsuperscript{\selectfont\@thefnmark}%
    \fi}}
```

What on earth might they have been trying to accomplish here?  Compare the kernel definition of `\@makefnmark`:

```
\def\@makefnmark{\hbox{\@textsuperscript{\normalfont\@thefnmark}}
```

As far as I can tell, the redefinition in the style file accomplishes nothing constructive, but causes the first footnote in the document to puke up a "Font shape `U/lmr/m/n' undefined" warning message (the style file also applies `\usepackage{lmodern}` and `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`).

Comment: perhaps they tried to get some fancy numbers but forgot to set the fontfamily.

Comment: I think that they are trying to use the same command to construct different footnote marks?

Comment: Quite difficult to say. Doing `\selectfont` by itself does essentially nothing, unless there's some preliminary font selection code in the macro that calls `\@makefnmark`. And there should better be, or you get exactly the stated message. But note that there *is* `ucmr.fd`, so if the main font family is not changed from Computer Modern the message doesn't show.

Comment: Is there any news here?

Comment: Well, last I checked, this nonsense was still in $journal's style file, and I still have no idea what the point was, but they published my article without complaining about me having commented it out (along with fixing several other much more serious bugs)...